# How to configure Auctex to automatically use pdflatex for all Latex files?

Tags: init-file, latex, auctex

I mean by adding an entry to the .emacs file.

Comment: What version of auctex do you use? This is already the default in latest versions. Anyway, giving a look to the manual doesn't hurt ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In order to enable [PDF mode](https://gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Processor-Options) by default in all *TeX buffers add the following line to your init file:

```lisp
(with-eval-after-load "tex"
  (TeX-global-PDF-mode 1))
```

Note that this is the default in AUCTeX [since version 11.88](https://gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#News-in-11_002e88), so if you a have a recent version of the package you don't need it to change this by hand.

---

The function `with-eval-after-load` has been introduced in Emacs 24.4.  If you're running older versions of the program you have to use this syntax instead:

```lisp
(eval-after-load "tex"
  '(TeX-global-PDF-mode 1))
```

Comment: "Symbol's function definition is void: with-eval-after-load" I have version 11/87 on my Ubuntu 14.04. Maybe I should try to install the new version.

Comment: @Reza  See the updated answer.  I guess you're running also an old Emacs version.  Regarding AUCTeX, note it's available in ELPA, so you can install it using Emacs' built-in package manager (`M-x lisp-packages RET`).